# Are these historical records about Jesus' appearance accurate?

Tags: life-of-jesus

All says that Jesus has a blonde hair and blue eyes.

http://www.ecclesia.org/truth/evidence.html

Various sites report that.

How credible it is?
Sample:

> This is a reprinting of a letter from Pontius Pilate to Tiberius
>   Caesar describing the physical appearance of Jesus. Copies are in the
>   Congressional Library in Washington, D.C.
>
> ```
> To Tiberius Caesar:
> ```
>
> A young man appeared in Galilee preaching with humble unction, a new law in the Name of the God that had sent Him. At first I was
>   apprehensive that His design was to stir up the people against the
>   Romans, but my fears were soon dispelled. Jesus of Nazareth spoke
>   rather as a friend of the Romans than of the Jews. One day I observed
>   in the midst of a group of people a young man who was leaning against
>   a tree, calmly addressing the multitude. I was told it was Jesus. This
>   I could easily have suspected so great was the difference between Him
>   and those who were listening to Him. His golden colored hair and beard
>   gave to his appearance a celestial aspect. He appeared to be about 30
>   years of age. Never have I seen a sweeter or more serene countenance.
>   What a contrast between Him and His bearers with their black beards
>   and tawny complexions! Unwilling to interrupt Him by my presence, I
>   continued my walk but signified to my secretary to join the group and
>   listen. Later, my secretary reported that never had he seen in the
>   works of all the philosophers anything that compared to the teachings
>   of Jesus. He told me that Jesus was neither seditious nor rebellious,
>   so we extended to Him our protection. He was at liberty to act, to
>   speak, to assemble and to address the people. This unlimited freedom
>   provoked the Jews -- not the poor but the rich and powerful.
>
> ```
> Later, I wrote to Jesus requesting an interview with Him at the Praetorium. He came. When the Nazarene made His appearance I was
> ```
>
> having my morning walk and as I faced Him my feet seemed fastened with
>   an iron hand to the marble pavement and I trembled in every limb as a
>   guilty culprit, though he was calm. For some time I stood admiring
>   this extraordinary Man. There was nothing in Him that was repelling,
>   nor in His character, yet I felt awed in His presence. I told Him that
>   there was a magnetic simplicity about Him and His personality that
>   elevated Him far above the philosophers and teachers of His day.
>
> ```
> Now, Noble Sovereign, these are the facts concerning Jesus of Nazareth and I have taken the time to write you in detail concerning
> ```
>
> these matters. I say that such a man who could convert water into
>   wine, change death into life, disease into health; calm the stormy
>   seas, is not guilty of any criminal offense and as others have said,
>   we must agree -- truly this is the Son of God!
>
> ```
> Your most obedient servant,
> Pontius Pilate
> ```

Note: I am looking for answers along, how credible gospel of Pilate is, etc.

Comment: You might want to change your question to are historical secular records of Jesus accurate, as part of your question is a duplicate as Affable noted, especially the title as it stands just about appearance is duplicate.

Comment: I changed the title. I do not think it's similar. Not all europeans have blonde hair and blue eyes.

Comment: If you want to ask a question specifically about how this source is viewed, please make your question about that. The question of Jesus looks has already been asked, and it would be the scope of answers to bring up this source if applicable. Right now your question is half and half. Decide what you want it to be about and ask a direct question about that. Thanks.

Answer (score 6):

**These sorts of records are dubious to say the least.**

For the first case **Josephus would never have claimed Jesus to be the Messiah, as he seems to have here**:

> Now, there was about this time Jesus, a wise man, if it be lawful to call him a man, for he was a doer of wonderful works—a teacher of such men as receive the truth with pleasure. He drew over to him both many of the Jews, and many of the Gentiles. He was [the] Christ; and when Pilate, at the suggestion of the principal men amongst us, had condemned him to the cross, those that loved him at the first did not forsake him, for he appeared to them alive again the third day, as the divine prophets had foretold these and ten thousand other wonderful things concerning him; and the tribe of Christians, so named from him, are not extinct at this day.( Josephus, F., & Whiston, W. (1987). The works of Josephus: Complete and unabridged. Peabody: Hendrickson.)

In fact Josephus seems to deliberately not refer to Jesus at all accept in a very minimalistic way. I can’t remember but I think only 2-3 times does Josephus refer at all to Jesus or events at that time. This would be more believable and understandable as Josephus was a historian that was opposed to Christianity. Jesus would have been a black eye to his valued history and pride of his treasured nation, which he himself fought as a soldier to defend. **It is therefore nearly unanimously understood by Christians that Josephus’s text was exaggerated or otherwise corrupted by a monk/scribe or who have you.**

Many think there was an original smaller reference by Josephus, but trying to decipher what it may have been is impossible. One good theory is found in a tenth-century Arabic copy but even this seems (to me) to have words that are too kind for what Josephus would have thought about Jesus:

> At this time there was a wise man who was called Jesus. And his conduct was good and [he] was known to be virtuous. Many people from among the Jews and other nations became his disciples. Pilate condemned him to be crucified and to die. And those who had become his disciples did not abandon his discipleship. They reported that he had appeared to them three days after his crucifixion and that he was alive; accordingly, he was perhaps the messiah concerning whom the prophets have recounted wonders.( Geisler, N. L. (1999). Baker encyclopedia of Christian apologetics. Baker Reference Library (254). Grand Rapids, MI: Baker Books.
>   )

**The other quotes that make Jesus seem like a European with ‘blue eyes’ and ‘blonde hair’ is clearly corruptions and falsifications of historical documents.** Whether they are entire fabrications or just corruptions of earlier records are somewhat beside the point. It is simple outrageous nonsense. The Bible says that there was nothing about Jesus that attracted men to him. If he was walking around like a European runway model it would fly right against the few biblical descriptions of his appearance. Not only so but it would have attracted so many comments about such strange look for a Jew. Our only expectation of his physical appearance is that he looked like an ordinary Jew. That means he would have most likely had olive skin and dark hair.

> For he grew up before him like a young plant, and like a root out of dry ground; he had no form or majesty that we should look at him, and no beauty that we should desire him. He was despised and rejected by men; a man of sorrows, and acquainted with grief; and as one from whom men hide their faces he was despised, and we esteemed him not. The Holy Bible: English Standard Version. 2001 (Is 53:2–3).

If there are a few Jews that have blonde hair and blue eyes then I suppose it is a possibility but very doubtful. Also his hair was probably short. He was not a hippie like many movies make him out to be. It was considered shameful for men to have long hair by Jews in biblical times unless under a Nazarene vow like Samson, which Jesus was not under.

Comment: >Josephus would never have claimed Jesus to be the Messiah, as he seems to have here:  



>He was [the] Christ;  

Looks like he did tho. 
Christ comes from the Greek word χριστός (chrīstós), meaning "anointed one". The word is derived from the Greek verb χρίω (chrī́ō), meaning "to anoint." In the Greek Septuagint, χριστός was a semantic loan used to translate the Hebrew מָשִׁיחַ (Mašíaḥ, messiah), meaning "⁠[one who is] anointed".

Answer (score 2):

Various cultures throughout the world tend to depict Jesus and looking like people in their culture.  This is seen in art from Africa and South America with Jesus seen looking like the people native to those regions.

The Bible and other historical records hold Jesus to be Jewish, so it is likely that he looked similar to other Jews if his day.